# Convert yyyyMMdd string into datetime in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a birthdate column with date in form of '20100731', I want to convert it into datetime therefore I can get its user's age.

I've tried multiple casting however no luck.

I can only think of doing

```
year(current_date) - cast(substr('20100731', 1,4) as int)
```

This works fine but I want to know way to convert 'yyyyMMdd' string into datetime format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using [`DATE_PARSE`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) to convert the string input into a date, then take the difference in years to the current date:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF('year', DATE_PARSE('20100731', '%Y%m%d'), CURRENT_DATE) AS age
FROM yourTable;
```